# Dynamically add filter options in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

Hello I have a small project in which I want to have perform search from multiple dynamically added text fields.

This is how I add the search fields:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="choice in choices">
     <button ng-show="showAddChoice(choice)" ng-click="addNewChoice()">Add another choice</button>
     <input type="text" ng-model="choice.name" name="" placeholder="Search criteria">
</div>
```

And later I have a table with ng-repeat and here is that part:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="todo in todos | filter: {filter from all fields}">
     .......
    </tr>
```

What I want to do is to have the contents filtered with all dynamically added search fields.

Comment: Can you submit a jsFiddle for this. I haven't tested it but try ng-repeat="todo in todos | filter: choices" and it may work.

Comment: Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nikolakoco/3Zj8S/3/) for this. And no filter: choices is not working :/

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create your own filter to handle that. I've gone ahead and gotten you started.

```
        $scope.myFilter = function(input){
            for(var key in input){
                for(var x = 0; x < $scope.choices.length; x++){
                    if(input[key] == $scope.choices[x].name){
                     return true;   
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Here is the jsFiddle of the output: http://jsfiddle.net/wsPrv/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the filter, do the filtering in the controller yourself. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jain208/3Zj8S/6/) is the updated fiddle with the solution. In the first textbox, replace choice1 with "some" and you will see the todo with text "Some stuff" being displayed.

See the relevant part below. For details, see the fiddle.

```
        $scope.$watch('choices', function(newValue) {
            $scope.DisplayedTodos = [];
            // Filter items here and push to DisplayedTodos. Use DisplayedTodos to display todos
        }, true);
```

Comment: YEs but this still doesn't do what I need. I need what is filtered through the first filter, those results to be filtered again with the second, third etc.

Comment: Hi, you just need to tweak the code inside the $watch to filter the data the way you want it to. I can change the code and do it for you, but really that's not the purpose of stackoverflow.com.